# How to backup the generator cache/settings for cmake gui on windows?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

We are developing a module for opencv to use internal and we would like not to check in the full opencv to TFS.

Is there any way to save all the settings from the cmake gui application such when a new developer joins the team he can easily just download opencv and include the settings for generating the solution files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a CMakeCache.txt file in your build directory. It stores the values changed in the gui application.
If you copy this to a new build and reload the cache, the settings should be restored and you can generate the build files.